# handle parent state in child component

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I need to handle the state of my parent component in the child component.

consider following code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        details: 'this is a macbook',
        image: require('./Images/macbook.jpg'),
        price: '1000$',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        details: 'this is a PS4 pro',
        image: require('./Images/ps4pro.jpeg'),
        price: '500$',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        details: 'this is a beats',
        image: require('./Images/beats.jpeg'),
        price: '200$',
      },
    ]
  }

  showProds = () => {
    let prods = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.products.length - 1; i++) {
      prods.push(<Product key={this.state.products[i].id} id={this.state.products[i].id} details={this.state.products[i].details} img={this.state.products[i].image} />)
    }
    return prods;
  }

  delete = () => {
  //handle deleting a product
  }

  render() {
    return <ScrollView>
      {this.showProds()}
    </ScrollView>
  }
}
```

as you can see this is my main (parent) component which has a state that is an array of example products I made a loop through them to show on screen and here is my product component:

```
const Product = (props) => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <View style={styles.prod}>
                <Text style={styles.prod_details}>{props.details}</Text>
                <Image style={styles.img} source={props.img} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.btn}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.Delete()}> //my handler is here
                    <Text style={styles.btn_text}>Delete</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View >
    )
}
```

I need to have my handler in the TouchableOpacity element (each product has a TO handler) so I can handle my parent state in the delete function. but this way leads to `undefined is not an object` error.

how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a referrence of function to child element like this:

```
function passThis() {...}
<SomeElement onSomeEvent={passThis}>
//in an element
function SomeElement(props){
  return (
    <Element onEvent={props.onSomeEvent}/>
  )
}
```

Also, I would advise you look into [functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) in react, [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and [array methods](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/sneak-peak-of-map-filter-and-reduce-in-javascript-79d38181a48) that substitute loops.
So, your components would be beter like this:

```
//App.js
const App = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState(someStartArray)
    const addProducts = (newItem) => setProducts(prev => [...prev, newItem])
    const delProducts = (delItem) => 
        setProducts(prev => prev.filter(item => item.id != delItem.id))
    
    return (
        <ScrollView>{
            products.map(item => (<Product {...item, delProducts} />)}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
//Product.js
const Product = ({id, details, image, handleDelete}) => (
    <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={styles.prod}>
           <Text style={styles.prod_details}>{details}</Text>
           <Image style={styles.img} source={img} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleDelete}> //your handler is here
               <Text style={styles.btn_text}>Delete</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View >
)
```